# Counting properties in an array

Tags: javascript, iteration, dynamic-arrays, naming-conventions

I am trying to count properties in a dynamically generated array. The array programs is created inside an object as follows:

```
state_list.push({name: state, undergrad: 0, grad: 0, total: 0, programs: []});
```

and then latter it is populated like this:

```
n = findWithAttr(state_list, 'name', state);
//n = the index of property "name" with value of "state" in state_list
if(!(program in state_list[n]["programs"])) {           
state_list[n]["programs"][program] = 1;
} else {
state_list[n]["programs"][program]++;
}
```

Next I need to total up the number of programs that have been placed in the array, and had hoped to do it with:

```
programs = state.programs;
console.log(programs.length);
```

but this returns 0.

here is the array if I log(programs):

```
Array[0]
History, MA: 3
Info Assurance & Security, MS: 1
International Literacy, MED: 1
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0]
main.js:237
```

It seems like it is placing all the programs in the array as one string... or something. I would love to have them indexed and have the ability to iterate over them. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is `program` in your if statement?

Comment: Public Administration, MPA   <-- this is an example of the log output of program it is created with "program = data[i]["Academic Program"]"

Comment: were you able to resolve your issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is what I ended up doing:

```
programs = state.programs;
keys = Object.keys(programs);
//this creates an indexed array of each property in programs
size = keys.length;
//this gives me the length of the new array, which I can use for pagination
```

then I was able to iterate over them like so:

```
offset = 0;
results = 24;
start = 0;              
$(keys).each(function() {
   if((start >= offset)&&(start < (offset+results))) {
   //this conditional gives me the pagination   
      $("#programResult").append("<li>"+this+": "+programs[this]+"</li>");
   }
   start++;
});
```

which gives me a result which reads like: "History, MA: 1"

Answer (score 1):

```
programs = state.programs;
console.log(programs.length);
```

will return the length of the array correctly if state refers to an object in the state_list array.

My guess is that `program` in your code is not a number, and the programs are being inserted as object properties rather than array indices.  length will only increase if you're actually adding things in the form programs[].  If `program` is a non-numeric string, you will be editing properties of the array not indices, and these will not increase the length.